# Setting the value of an element within a nested array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a simple 10x10 Array so that I can create Conway's Game of Life, but I'm running into some strange behavior. First I initialize the board:

```
@board = Array.new(10, Array.new(10))
(0..9).each do |row|
    (0..9).each do |column|
        @board[row][column] = rand(0..1)
    end
end
```

Which produces this:

```
1000000111
1000000111
1000000111
1000000111
1000000111
1000000111
1000000111
1000000111
1000000111
1000000111
1000000111
```

Looks fishy but it's entirely possible that this could be generated randomly. The real problems start when I try to set the value of an individual cell. When I change the value, it sets the entire column to that value! For example, let's say I change the value of the first cell:

```
@board[0][0] = 0
```

What I get is:

```
0000000111
0000000111
0000000111
0000000111
0000000111
0000000111
0000000111
0000000111
0000000111
0000000111
0000000111
```

What gives? Why does the value change for ALL cells in column 0 instead of just the cell at 0, 0?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720932/create-two-dimensional-arrays-and-access-sub-arrays-in-ruby

Comment: Not directly relevant to your problem, but take a look at `narray` for multi-dimensional numerical arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. When I initialized `@board` with `Array.new(10, Array.new(10))`, it created an Array of 10 identical Arrays. That is, each Array had the same object_id.

```
@board[0].object_id
=> 22148328
@board[1].object_id
=> 22148328
```

I solved the issue by using the `map` method:

```
@board = Array.new(10).map{ |x| Array.new(10) }
```

Comment: Note you could use the block form of [`Array::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-c-new) to get distinct row objects as well. `@board = Array.new(10) { Array.new(10) }`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That looks a lot cleaner than using map.