# How does ruby works with array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am facing something i do not fully understand.

I have an array whose elements are arrays.

So I have two nested loops, in the inner loop I fill my inner array
then in the outer loop i fill the  outer array with the inner array.

```
arr=[]
mat=[]
for m in (0..1)
  for k in (0..1)
    arr[k]=rand.to_s
  end
  mat[m]=arr
end
```

At the end my matrix is filled with two array; each array contains the values calculated in the last iteration.
If i want the first element in matrix to contain the first computed array I have to reinitialize the arr object at each loop.
So it seems that assignment is made by reference until the arr object is "cleaned". If I add

```
mat[m]=arr
arr=[]
```

all works as expected: mat[0] will contain the array computed in the first loop, and mat[1] will contain the array computed in the second loop.

Is this by design or is it an undesired side effect?
This is happening only if I assign arrays as array elements. If if fill an array with simple string variables in a loop all goes as expected.

I know that it is good programming practice to avoid reusing objects, but this behavior is anyway strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your arr variable's contents is being overwritten with each iteration: the `arr[k]` overwrites whatever is in there already. The arr variable needs to be local to the block instead:

```
mat = []
2.times do             # avoid for... use iterators instead
  row = []
  2.times do 
    row << rand.to_s
  end
  mat << row
end
```

Comment: @Niel: That was more or less what I meant, actually. My non-native English might be getting in the way though. ;-) I've rephrased it in a hopefully better way.

Comment: Yes I think it is good enough now that I deleted my comment and +1-ed

Comment: @Denis: Thanks, i already found that this is the way it works. The question is if it is correct. I expect that each time I do mat << row  , a copy of row is added as a new element of mat. This happens only if row is re-initialzied at each iteration. Otherwise mat is added with a pointer to row, not with is content. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Denis: Maybe now I got it. It is a matter of variable scoping. It is wrong to declare row outside of both loops.

Comment: @kranz: yeah, your specific issue was scoping. Regarding what gets added in `mat =` or `mat[m] =`, you're always adding pointers to objects. Without the proper scope, you'd end up referencing the same row twice, and you can see that by running it through [pretty print](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html).)

Answer (score 0):

I like the approach of [using hashes instead of multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1721693/1172122).

How about this:

```
def creat­e_matrix x, y, conte­nt = nil, &block
  rows = (0...x­).to_a
  cols = (0...y­).to_a
  indices = rows.­product cols
  matrix = {}
  indices.ea­ch { |inde­x| matri­x[index] = ( block­_given? ? yield­( index ) : conte­nt ) }
  matrix
end
```

Then do:

```
matrix = create_matrix( 2, 2 ) { rand.to_s }
```

You will get a hash, that you can access like this:

```
matrix[[0, 1]] #note the double brackets
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
(1..4).map{rand}.each_slice(2).to_a
```