# Ruby change value in two dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to change a value of a two dimensional array.

This is the array:

```
class Test
    def initialize
        @single = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        @double = [@single, @single, @single, @single]
    end
    def changeValue i, j
        @double[i][j] = nil
    end
    def showDouble
        return @double
    end
end
```

I want to change a value in the double array (the two dimensional array). If I want to change the value of 9 in the first array, then I should do something like this:

```
test = Test.new
test.changeValue 0, 8
puts test.showDouble
```

When I do this, then the value of 9 is in every array nil. I only want to change it in one array. Any help is welcome! :)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "doesn't work"? It works fine for me.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720932/create-two-dimensional-arrays-and-access-sub-arrays-in-ruby

Comment: Note that when using the same, unduplicated array (`single`) in all elements of the the double array, changing the contents of `single` in one row will change it in other rows as well (since it's really the same object).

Comment: i tried that on my irb console and it was working, what error are you getting.

Comment: I'm updating it! Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: This is really interesting.

Comment: Thank you, I'm just trying to get this functional. :)

Comment: This looks bad but try this, actually here i m creating different objects with Array.new `@double = [Array.new(@single), Array.new(@single), Array.new(@single), Array.new(@single)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array `@double` actually contains four references to the **same** array `@single`, which is why you're getting the behavior you describe.

Initialize `@double = [@single.clone, @single.clone, @single.clone, @single.clone]` to get independent (but initially identical) sub-arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
@double = [@single, @single, @single, @single]
```

you fill array with same object, in `changeValue` you change it, so it is being changed 4 times for `@double`. If you want 4 different objects, init `@double` as:

```
@double = [@single.dup, @single.dup, @single.dup, @single.dup]
```